# regular shaped tree fold left scala implementation

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, tree

I'm trying to implement a tail-recursive `foldLeft` function for a regular shaped tree. The exercise comes from the book, "[The Science of Functional Programming](https://github.com/winitzki/sofp/blob/master/sofp-src/sofp.pdf)," in exercise 3.3.5.3.

Until now, I was able to do the exercises but I don't know what I'm missing in this one.

There's is a definition for the regular shaped tree:

```
sealed trait RTree[A]
final case class Leaf[A](x: A) extends RTree[A]
final case class Branch[A](xs: RTree[(A,A)]) extends RTree[A]
```

The method signature and expected result:

```
@tailrec
def foldLeft[A,R](t: RTree[A])(init: R)(f: (R,A)=>R): R= ???

foldLeft(Branch(Branch(Leaf(((1,2),(3,4))))))(0)(_+_)
//10
```

The biggest problem so far is that I don't know how to match and access the element inside the case class of `Branch`. I can only match the `Leaf` and `Branch` (and not the leaf's inside a branch) and because of that the recursion has no end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but for now I have only NON tail-recursive implementation.

```
def foldLeft[A, R](t: RTree[A])(init: R)(f: (R, A) => R): R = {
      t match {
        case Leaf(value) => f(init, value)
        case Branch(tree) =>
          foldLeft(tree)(init) {
            case (result, (left, right)) => f(f(result, left), right)
          }
      }
    }
```

**UPDATE**: As was said in comments section to this answer this is actually tail rec implementation, excuse me, for confusing you.

Comment: You are wrong. That **is** tail-recursive. (Which means your answer is right.)

Comment: Excuse me, please - I've tried to complile this code with @tailrec - but scalac said this method cannot be optimized. My Scala version -  2.12.6

Comment: @jwvh ok, thank you very much for your help, I'll update answer if you don't mind then.